# I am working on a roblox search slash command but it isn't exactly working correctly, I would like some support of revamping these

Tags: discord.py, roblox

I want to make a /searchroblox command. Below is what I have

main.py:

````
from roblox import *
@tree.command(name = "searchroblox", description = "Sends roblox username", guild = discord.Object(id = 1080684956130496542))
async def searchroblox(ctx, *, username: str):
  robloxuser = robloxUser(username)
  embed = discord.Embed(color=0xa3fff7, title=f"Info for {username}")
  embed.add_field(name="Username",value="`" + username + "`")
  embed.add_field(name="Display Name", value="`" + robloxuser.getdn() + "`")
  embed.add_field(name="User ID", value="`" + str(robloxuser.getid()) + "`")
  embed.add_field(name="Description", value= "```" + (robloxuser.getdesc() or "No description") + "```")
  await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)
  if isinstance(ctx.channel, discord.DMChannel):
   return
````

roblox.py:

```
from ro_py import Client
robloxclient = Client()

class robloxUser:
    def __init__(self, rblox):
        rbloxuser = robloxclient.get_user_by_username(rblox)
    def username(self, rbloxuser):
        self.__user = rbloxuser.name
        
    def display_name(self, rbloxuser):
        self.__dn = rbloxuser.display_name
        
    def userid(self, rbloxuser):
        self.__id = rbloxuser.id
        
    def description(self, rbloxuser):
        self.__description = rbloxuser.description or "No description"

    def getruser(self):
        return self.__user
    def getdn(self):
        return self.__dn
    def getid(self):
        return self.__id
    def getdesc(self):
        return self.__description
```

After running the code it would show.

```
main.py:145: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.get_user_by_username' was never awaited
  robloxuser = robloxUser(username)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
2023-04-03 20:30:43 ERROR    discord.app_commands.tree Ignoring exception in command 'searchroblox'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Pixel/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 842, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
  File "main.py", line 148, in searchroblox
    embed.add_field(name="Display Name", value="`" + robloxuser.getdn() + "`")
  File "/home/runner/Pixel/roblox.py", line 22, in getdn
    return self.__dn
AttributeError: 'robloxUser' object has no attribute '_robloxUser__dn'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Pixel/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1248, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "/home/runner/Pixel/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 867, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
  File "/home/runner/Pixel/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 860, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'searchroblox' raised an exception: AttributeError: 'robloxUser' object has no attribute '_robloxUser__dn'
```

What would I have to do to fix this. I commented all this to avoid problems with the rest of my code by the way.

robloxUser keeps saying it doesn't connect with ro_py file set after I do use it.

Edits: I removed roblox.py:
main.py:

````
import ro_py
from ro_py import Client
@tree.command(name = "searchroblox", description = "Sends roblox username", guild = discord.Object(id = 1080684956130496542))
async def searchroblox(ctx, *, username: str):
  x = Client()

  robloxuser = await x.get_user_by_username(username)
  embed = discord.Embed(color=0xa3fff7, title=f"Info for {username}")
  embed.add_field(name="Username",value="`" + username + "`")
  embed.add_field(name="Display Name", value="`" + robloxuser.display_name + "`")
  embed.add_field(name="User ID", value="`" + str(robloxuser.id) + "`")
  embed.add_field(name="Description", value= "```" + (robloxuser.description or "No description") + "```")
  await ctx.response.send_message(embed=embed)
  if isinstance(ctx.channel, discord.DMChannel):
   return
````

This is my new code, below shows what I got, I am commenting it again just in case it crashs my other code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Pixel/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 842, in _do_call
    return await self._callback(interaction, **params)  # type: ignore
  File "main.py", line 147, in searchroblox
    robloxuser = await x.get_user_by_username(username)
  File "/home/runner/Pixel/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ro_py/client.py", line 131, in get_user_by_username
    raise UserDoesNotExistError
ro_py.utilities.errors.UserDoesNotExistError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/Pixel/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/app_commands/tree.py", line 1248, in _call
    await command._invoke_with_namespace(interaction, namespace)
  File "/home/runner/Pixel/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 867, in _invoke_with_namespace
    return await self._do_call(interaction, transformed_values)
  File "/home/runner/Pixel/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/app_commands/commands.py", line 860, in _do_call
    raise CommandInvokeError(self, e) from e
discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError
```

: Command 'searchroblox' raised an exception: UserDoesNotExistError:

Comment: The Title is really bad ("*I am working on a roblox search slash command but it isn't exactly working correctly, I would like some support of revamping these*"), only "*roblox search slash command*" are "useful" in it, the rest is just "noise", could you give a more descriptive Title to your Question...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The error

```
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

This warning means that the code was not awaited. The function used is asynchronous meaning that you have to use the `await` keyword. The await keyword can only be used in asynchronous functions.

### You don't need to create an entire roblox.py file

The library does all the work for you. Instead, do the following within your already async function:

```
robloxuser = await client.get_user_by_username(username)
```

Then in the embed, you can use the properties of the `robloxuser` variable.

````
  embed.add_field(name="User ID", value="`" + str(robloxuser.id) + "`")
  embed.add_field(name="Description", value= "```" + (robloxuser.description or "No description") + "```")
````

See a nice [example](https://github.com/ro-py/ro.py/blob/main/examples/user_information_by_username.py) here.

### Your update

Your error:

```
: Command 'searchroblox' raised an exception: UserDoesNotExistError:
```

This just means that the user you inputted does not exist. Use a try except statement to return that to the user who ran the command.